# How to use content of variable in bash to pass to find in script?

Tags: linux, string, bash, find, quotes

In a bash script I'm trying to use the content of a variable to be used as options for the find command:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE_EXTENSIONS=( txt png jpg )

FIRST=1
for FILE_EXTENSION in ${FILE_EXTENSIONS[@]} 
do
#   echo "$FILE_EXTENSION"
    if [[ $FIRST == 1 ]]
    then
        FIND_FILTER="-iname '*.$FILE_EXTENSION'"
        FIRST=0
    else
        FIND_FILTER="${FIND_FILTER} -o -iname '*.$FILE_EXTENSION'"
    fi
done
# Read and write only for user and group, ignore case '-iname'
#find . -type f "$FIND_FILTER" -exec chmod 660 {} \;
echo Find filter: $FIND_FILTER
# This might work with some already provided suggestions:
find . -type f $FIND_FILTER
# But this fails so far
find . -type f $FIND_FILTER -exec chmod 660 {} \;        
#EOF
```

The aim is to set proper access rights as for what ever reason quite some files (such as pictures or office documents) are marked executable.

So in reality the script above has several arrays with file extensions concatenated, but the script shows the problem.

The first approach would have been to iterate over the final array and call find each time. But from a runtime point of view it would be stupid to search each time over and over again.

I also could simply do this in python but for once I thought I would like to solve it with linux basic means in bash.

It looks like the content of the FIND_FILTER variable is correct (at least what is printed with echo) but then ... it doesn't work.

Any suggestions what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started using arrays (nearly) correctly, but then abandoned them for a space-separated string. Keep using arrays.

1. Always quote the expansion of an `@`-indexed array; otherwise, there is no reason to use `@` over `*`.
2. As a general rule, avoid all-caps variables names; they are (mostly) reserved for use by the shell.
3. Enclose the filters joined by `-o` in escaped parentheses so that `find` treats them as a single condition to be met in addition to the `-type` primary.
4. Use `-exec ... +` so that `chmod` can operate on multiple files per call, rather than calling it once for each file separately.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
file_extensions=( txt png jpg )

first=1
for ext in "${file_extensions[@]}"
do
#   echo "$ext"
    if [[ $first == 1 ]]
    then
        find_filter=(-iname "*.$ext")
        first=0
    else
        find_filter+=( -o -iname "*.$ext")
    fi
done


# Read and write only for user and group, ignore case '-iname'
find . -type f \( "${find_filter[@]}" \) -exec chmod 660 +
```

Comment: @Benoit Thanks for cleaning up my hastily written answer.

Comment: Thank you @chepner - that saved my day. 
I now know better how to use arrays and most important about the find syntax with ( ) and the need of quoting them!

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the reason why it does not work

```
$ find . $FIND_ARGS &       # Does not work
[1] 6312    
$ cat /proc/6312/cmdline
find . -iname '*.png'

$ find . -iname '*.png' &   # Works
[1] 8901
$ cat /proc/8901/cmdline
find . -iname *.png
```

So, the quotes when invoking the command directly are only there for bash not to expand the arguments. When you start the command indirectly, you have to remove those quotes.

Comment: Thanks Benoit, I confirm that this works for the simple case (even I don't understand why). But as sooon as I try to use the resut as argument to ' -exec chmod 660 {} \;' it fails with:
    Find filter: -iname filter.txt -o -iname z.png -o -iname *.jpg
    find: unknown predicate `-iname *.txt -o -iname *.png -o -iname *.jpg'